# Array_search in object array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have this small search function in my page;
$searchWord is the word that I need to look for in my array.
The array looks a bit like this:

```
stdClass Object ( 
[ActionScopeId] => 181365 
[DateChanged] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00 
[DateCreated] => 2013-08-20T13:59:33.053 
[Description] => Snelheid test 
[MessageCode] => C0000448220 
) 
stdClass Object ( 
[ActionScopeId] => 181364 
[DateChanged] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00 
[DateCreated] => 2013-08-14T10:08:50.707 
[Description] => Test 
[MessageCode] => C0000448219 
)
```

Now, for example; I want to look for the word 'Test'. When it's found, I want to print the ActionScopeId and DateCreated with it.

This is my code:

```
$roc = array('relation' => $_SESSION['username']);
$rocresponse = $wcfclient->ReadOpenCalls($roc);
foreach ($rocresponse->ReadOpenCallsResult as $key => $value){
  foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1){
    if (array_search($searchWord,$value1)){
      echo $value1->ActionScopeId;
    }
  }
}
```

But, the result I get is always empty. What am I doing wrong?

---

I fixed it, when trying to search into an **object** you can use this function:

```
    function in_object($val, $obj){

    if($val == ""){
        trigger_error("in_object expects parameter 1 must not empty", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    if(!is_object($obj)){
        $obj = (object)$obj;
    }

    foreach($obj as $key => $value){
        if(!is_object($value) && !is_array($value)){
            if($value == $val){
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            return in_object($val, $value);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then look for it in this way:

```
if (in_object($searchWord,$value)){
```

Comment: Put `print_r`'s to figure out where you start to lose your data..

Comment: The print of $value1 is the array I show on top, without the array_search() it also shows me the values of $value1->ActionScopeId etc.

Comment: Yep, there you go. `array_search` searches in an array, but `$value1` is actually an object. (If I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using this function:

```
function in_object($val, $obj){

if($val == ""){
    trigger_error("in_object expects parameter 1 must not empty", E_USER_WARNING);
    return false;
}
if(!is_object($obj)){
    $obj = (object)$obj;
}

foreach($obj as $key => $value){
    if(!is_object($value) && !is_array($value)){
        if($value == $val){
            return true;
        }
    }else{
        return in_object($val, $value);
    }
}
return false;
```

And then look for it in this way:

```
if (in_object($searchWord,$value)){}
```